# How do I render Mustache templates with JSON with no root node

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, mustache

I am building a small page which calls an API using jquery's getJSON and then renders the data using a mustache template (at least that's the plan). However my JSON does not have a node root and am unable to loop through the JSONs response data using the proper mustache mechanics.

```
//start
file : jsonresponse.jsonp

?([{"CountryIsoAlpha3Code":"AFG","CountryName":"Afghanistan"},
{"CountryIsoAlpha3Code":"ALA","CountryName":"Åland Islands"},
{"CountryIsoAlpha3Code":"ALB","CountryName":"Albania"}])
//end

//start
file: tmpl.mustache

<option value="{{CountryIsoAlpha3Code}}">{{CountryName}}</option>
//end

//start
file: render.js

$.getJSON(jsonresponse.jsonp, function(data) { 
   var tpl = tmpl.mustache,
   i=data.length,
   html = '';
     while(i--){
       html = html + mustache.render(tpl, data[i]);
     }

//end
```

I realize this is completely wrong (in the template usage only, assume I am actually passing the data and template properly) but it does work. but what if I want to do the follow... HOW DO I DO IT!?:

```
//start
//file : daydreamer.mustache

<h1>This title is only awesome when it's rendered once</h1>
{{#}}  //no root node attempt at recursive templating rendering
     <option value="{{CountryIsoAlpha3Code}}">{{CountryName}}</option>
{{/}}

//end
```

If this is unclear please let me know I know a poor question is an eye sore. I will try to edit as soon as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the pieces you control on this application/use case, you have 2 possible fixes: either modify the JSON data to include such root node, **or** add that root node to your data on your end.

The mustache template will need to get modified as follows for both solutions:

```
{{#options}}
    <option value="{{CountryIsoAlpha3Code}}">{{CountryName}}</option>
{{/options}}
```

Now you either wrap the data directly on the server **or** on your end, and then the `getJSON` call will be like this for the second solution (for the first one, replace the `{options: data}` wrapper with just `data`). I'm going with the second one assuming you can't control the server side because that API is fixed/mandated by somebody else:

```
$.getJSON("jsonresponse.jsonp", function(data) { 
    var tpl = tmpl.mustache,
        html = '';

    html = mustache.render(tpl, {options: data});
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much for this. I will gladly give you an extra +25 for this one ! I also think I will change my answer to better reflect the main issue